# Sql query to check if the table value exists between range of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am working in SQLServer database. I have the following scenario,

My application runs every weekday of the month, when it runs it puts an entry into the table '**CONTROL**' into the '**businessDate**' column.

Is there a way to find out what are the days the application did not run for a given month. Is it possible to achieve it in a single query ?

Comment: Well, the first thing you will need is a date table (most probably logical table, not physical), and from there the junction pretty much writes itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need a calendar table.  Then select from that table left joined to your CONTROL table on date, where the month is what you're looking for, and where the control table is null (to show just exclusions).

```
DECLARE @Month int = 1 //For January

SELECT BaseDate
FROM CalendarTable cal
LEFT OUTER JOIN ControlTable con
    ON cal.BaseDate = con.businessDate //make sure to cast as a date if it's a datetime
WHERE MONTH(cal.BaseDate) = @Month
AND con.businessDate IS NULL
```